# ASP.NET MVC 5; using Office 365 online doc viewer to display word docs showing up in tiny thin window

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, office365

We have been trying to display a Word document (.docx) in an iframe on our website using the Office 365 service.  Our document is stored in One-Drive for business online and shared appropriately.  We signed in and got a link to our document using various means available on Office 365 online.  We then stored the link in our SQL database.  Our website references the table with the stored URL and puts that information in the 'src' of the iframe and the document shows up in tiny sliver, despite setting the height of the iframe to 1100 and the width to 800.  Code is below:

**pseudo url**
https://microsoft-my.sharepoint.com/personal/accountName/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=blahblahblah&action=embedview

**Partial View code:**

```
@using Website.DataAccess.Models
@model List<Report>

@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var report in Model)
    {
        <div align="center">
            @switch (report.DocType)
            {
                case ".docx":
                    <iframe src="@report.URL" frameborder="0" style="width:100%; height:1050px;" scrolling="yes" sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
                    break;
                case ".mp4":
                    <video width="800" height="600" controls>
                        <source src="@report.URL" type="video/mp4"/>
                        Video not supported.
                    </video>
                    break;
                default:
                    <p>Document type not supported.</p>
                    break;
            }
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <a href="@report.URL">@report.Name</a>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <p>No files found.</p>
}

// don't honestly think this script is doing anything useful; just trying anyuthing
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if (typeof (EmbedManager) === undefined) {
            EmbedManager.loadResult();
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

We have tried for many hours to find a solution, including experimenting with the parameters of the url and the iframe and have come up with nothing.  We haven't found anyone out there with this problem.  Again, the viewport in the iframe is sometimes a centimeter tall, sometimes 5 centimeters tall, sometimes it shows the whole document.  We have tried setting the size both in style and outside of style and nothing.

The document displays fine when you paste it into the address bar of the browser, but not inside an iframe on our setup.  When running our site, nothing shows up in FireFox and Edge except an error saying we can't use an iframe for this content.  Shows up in IE and Chrome though, just more often than not it's inside a thin viewport.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay sorry everyone.  Looks like UI from the main view was somehow interfering with the viewer's ability to display correctly.  We are not sure what caused it, but have since moved partial view to a new page to solve the problem.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question and think about.

-L_Laxton